# WebFluxTags::uri returning wrong tags

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I dont understand why this method is implemeted in the following way:

```
/**
 * Creates a {@code uri} tag based on the URI of the given {@code exchange}. Uses the
 * {@link HandlerMapping#BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE} best matching pattern if
 * available. Falling back to {@code REDIRECTION} for 3xx responses, {@code NOT_FOUND}
 * for 404 responses, {@code root} for requests with no path info, and {@code UNKNOWN}
 * for all other requests.
 * @param exchange the exchange
 * @return the uri tag derived from the exchange
 */
public static Tag uri(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    PathPattern pathPattern = exchange.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
    if (pathPattern != null) {
        return Tag.of("uri", pathPattern.getPatternString());
    }
    HttpStatus status = exchange.getResponse().getStatusCode();
    if (status != null) {
        if (status.is3xxRedirection()) {
            return URI_REDIRECTION;
        }
        if (status == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
            return URI_NOT_FOUND;
        }
    }
    String path = getPathInfo(exchange);
    if (path.isEmpty()) {
        return URI_ROOT;
    }
    return URI_UNKNOWN;
}
```

I find it strange that they use `exchange.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)` this results in lots of my request returning null and defaulting to unknown. However when checking the exchange `request.path` contains the path that I would like to use.

Why is not request.path used that always has a value?

How does `exchange.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)` work. I dont understand even what it does?

Why are some of my request returning null for `exchange.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)`, all controllers are implemented in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a request is received, it's mapped to a particular handler, be that a `@RequestMapping` method, a router function, or something else. This mapping process includes matching against a path pattern. The path pattern associated with the matched handler is stored in the exchange's `BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE`.

When creating the tags for a request-response exchange, the `BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE` is used to prevent the `uri` tag from having an unbounded set of values. For example, if a request with the URI `/users/123456`  has been matched to the pattern `/users/{id}`, the value of `BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE` will be `/users/{id}`. If the request's path was used, you'd end up with a different `uri` tag value for each user. With millions of users you'd end up with millions of values for the `uri` tag which would be detrimental to the monitoring system.

Even without millions of users, an attacker could attempt a denial of service attack on the monitoring system. By making millions of requests to `/users/{id}` with different values for id, they could flood the monitoring system with millions of values for the `uri` tag.

Unfortunately, I can't say with certainty why some requests have a `null` `BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE`. It could be that there's no matching handler and that the response will be a 404. This particular aspect of your question would probably be better addressed in a separate question with an accompanying example.